# CakePHP on adding a belongsTo table not found?

Tags: cakephp, belongs-to

I have a CakePHP model which looks like this (and works fine):

```
class Paper extends AppModel {
      var $name = 'Paper';
      var $displayField = 'id';
}
```

This gives no error since I have a `papers` table in my database.

When I change the model to so (I simply add that last line):

```
class Paper extends AppModel {
      var $name = 'Paper';
      var $displayField = 'id';

      var $belongsTo = 'User';
}
```

I get the error:

```
Missing Database Table

Error: Database table ps for model Papers was not found.

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\views\errors\missing_table.ctp
```

What could be going wrong that CakePHP suddenly assumes some first and last character nomenclature on adding a `belongsTo` line?

**EDIT**

I may be wrong with this, but shouldn't the error say `model Paper`? It's saying `Papers` instead. This happens after adding the `belongsTo` statement. Is this where the error is?

Comment: table "ps"? is your table not named "papers"? if not, you need to add var $useTable="ps";

Comment: My table IS named 'papers'. But it still says 'ps not found'
I want it to use 'papers'. In fact it does so until I add the belongsTo statement :/

Comment: How does the User model look like? If you have `$hasMany = 'Papers'` or something like that there you might get that error.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the `var $displayField = 'id';` line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue.

Simply put, model-model links are **not** a one-way street as the CakePHP documentation calls it.

For example if model A `belongsTo` model B, then model B MUST `hasOne` or `hasMany` model A.

In my case, syntax at the receiving end was faulty.